# How to use the "-notcontains" conditional parameter when querying a BlockedSendersAndDomains list in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a list of all mailboxes who DO NOT have "conostco.com" domain on their BlockedSendersAndDomains list.

by using

```
$test= Get-MailboxJunkemailconfiguration -Identity * | fl Displayname, BlockedSendersAndDomains
```

I can get a list of all the names and the Blocked domains/email addresses associated to those names but for my purpose I want to get a list of all of the names of the mailboxes that DO NOT contain the domain "conostco.com". Is there such way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample data you have given I am "assuming" BlockSendersAndDomains is an array.

So maybe you could do something like this then

```
$test= Get-MailboxJunkemailconfiguration -Identity * | % { $domains = $_.BlockedSendersAndDomains.GetEnumerator() | ? {$_ -notmatch 'conostco.com'}; $name = $_.displayname ; new-object PSObject -Property @{name=$displayname;domains=$domains} }
```

Again, there is no way for me to test, so see if that gives you a $test object collection which you can then re-use or just display, if you like.

Comment: I want to list users who do not have x domain in their Blocked domain list. The code you provided shows only people who have "conostco.com" AND any other domain they blocked themselves. Instead I want everyone who doesn't have a certain (lets name it conostco.com) domain added to their blocked list

Comment: Well, I am going by what you are describing, have no way of knowing what is the result of 'Get-MailboxJunkemailconfiguration -identity *', that being said if you used "-notmatch", I don't see how you are getting that result.

Comment: This is a sample of results when I do 'Get-MailboxJunkemailconfiguration -identity *'  

RunspaceId               : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Enabled                  : True
TrustedListsOnly         : False
ContactsTrusted          : False
TrustedSendersAndDomains : {}
BlockedSendersAndDomains : {conostco.com}
MailboxOwnerId           : XXXXX, XXXXXXX
Identity                 : XXXXX, XXXXXXX
IsValid                  : True

its a list of every employee showing what domain they have blocked

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration -Identity * | 
Where-Object {$_.BlockedSendersAndDomains -notlike '*conostco.com*' }
```